# Magento 2.1.4 installation always_populate_raw_post_data error

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to setup Magento 2.1.4 on my hosting and I receive this error:

> Your PHP Version is 5.6.13, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0.
>    `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be
>    removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please
>    open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If
>    you need more help please call your hosting provider.

I changed my php.ini file and php-fcgi.ini file in the hosting account and I still receive the same error.

I saw that on some places they recommend that users restart web-servers but how can I do that on my web hosting. Should I call them?

**Edit:**
I contacted my web hosting and I restarted the server and still the same error shows

Answer (score 1):

Remove the starting semicolon `;` from your php.ini the following code.

```
;always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

And then restart your xampp/wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the server needs to be restarted after changes like that.

Comment: I restarted the web server and still the same error continues to show